# Is there a more efficient way to write this for loop in bash?

Tags: bash, performance, for-loop, gdal

I have a for loop that downloads climate data and crops it to the extent of my study area. Technically it works, but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient approach than having the loop repeatedly try to make the directories.

I was thinking about nesting this loop inside one that calls a variable from an array and makes a directory for it, then runs gdal... but I'm not sure how that would work because the gdal lines are slightly different.

```
## INITIAL LOOP
for MM in 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 ; do 
    #download tmin data
    mkdir tmin
    cd tmin
    gdal_translate -projwin $ulx $uly $lrx $lry -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co ZLEVEL=9  /vsicurl/https://os.zhdk.cloud.switch.ch/envicloud/chelsa/chelsa_V1/climatologies/tmin/CHELSA_tmin10_${MM}_1979-2013_V1.2_land.tif  CHELSA_tmin10_${MM}_1979-2013_V1.2_land_crop.tif 
    cd ..
    #download precpitation data
    mkdir prec
    cd prec
    gdal_translate -projwin $ulx $uly $lrx $lry -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co ZLEVEL=9  /vsicurl/https://os.zhdk.cloud.switch.ch/envicloud/chelsa/chelsa_V1/climatologies/prec/CHELSA_prec_${MM}_V1.2_land.tif  CHELSA_prec_${MM}_V1.2_land_crop.tif 
    cd ..
    #download tmax data
    mkdir tmax
    cd tmax
    gdal_translate -projwin $ulx $uly $lrx $lry -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co ZLEVEL=9     /vsicurl/https://os.zhdk.cloud.switch.ch/envicloud/chelsa/chelsa_V1/climatologies/tmax/CHELSA_tmax10_${MM}_1979-2013_V1.2_land.tif CHELSA_tmax10_${MM}_1979-2013_V1.2_land_crop.tif 
    cd ..
done
```

```
#THOUGHTS
var_list=(tmin tmax prec) 

for var in ${var_list[@]} ; do
    mkdir $var
    cd $var
    for MM in 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 ; do 
        #download tmin data
        mkdir tmin
        cd tmin
        gdal_translate -projwin $ulx $uly $lrx $lry -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co ZLEVEL=9  /vsicurl/https://os.zhdk.cloud.switch.ch/envicloud/chelsa/chelsa_V1/climatologies/tmin/CHELSA_tmin10_${MM}_1979-2013_V1.2_land.tif  CHELSA_tmin10_${MM}_1979-2013_V1.2_land_crop.tif 
        cd ..
        #download precpitation data
        mkdir prec
        cd prec
        gdal_translate -projwin $ulx $uly $lrx $lry -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co ZLEVEL=9  /vsicurl/https://os.zhdk.cloud.switch.ch/envicloud/chelsa/chelsa_V1/climatologies/prec/CHELSA_prec_${MM}_V1.2_land.tif  CHELSA_prec_${MM}_V1.2_land_crop.tif 
        cd ..
        #download tmax data
        mkdir tmax
        cd tmax
        gdal_translate -projwin $ulx $uly $lrx $lry -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co ZLEVEL=9     /vsicurl/https://os.zhdk.cloud.switch.ch/envicloud/chelsa/chelsa_V1/climatologies/tmax/CHELSA_tmax10_${MM}_1979-2013_V1.2_land.tif CHELSA_tmax10_${MM}_1979-2013_V1.2_land_crop.tif 
        cd ..
    done
done
```

Comment: If you are worried about efficiency and are doing lots of high latency processing, I would suggest you try **GNU Parallel**. Put `[gnu-parallel]` into Stack Overflow searchbox.

Comment: Why are you creating same directories each loop? Don't you get "this directory already exists" errors? Run your script via http://shellcheck.net and fix all misteakes.

Comment: It doesn't give me an error, it just informs me that the directory has already been created. So I know its probably not the right way to make this loop, but the files populated where I wanted them to.  I am trying to get 1 folder for tmin, tmax, and prec and get all the associated files into their respective folder.

Comment: but.. why not just `mkdir tmun tmax prec` __before the loop__..

Comment: ok if I did that, I would still cd gdal_translate cd .. correct? I suppose I was just overcomplicating the loop then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the last arg for the `gdal_translate` calls is a file you wish to create, and assuming this argument can include a relative path to said file (to be created), how about:

```
mkdir -p tmin tmax prec           # '-p' suppresses the 'directory already exists' message

for MM in {01..12}
do
    # no ned for 'cd' calls if gdal_translate can write to a relative path/file, eg:

    gdal_translate ... tmin/CHELSA_tmin10_${MM}_1979-2013_V1.2_land_crop.tif 
    gdal_translate ... prec/CHELSA_prec_${MM}_V1.2_land_crop.tif 
    gdal_translate ... tmax/CHELSA_tmax10_${MM}_1979-2013_V1.2_land_crop.tif 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original code has the same effets as this:

```
var_list=(tmin tmax prec)

# make a hash array to hold tif files, with ${MM} to be eval'ed later:
declare -A xhash
xhash[tmin]="CHELSA_tmin10_\${MM}_1979-2013_V1.2_land_crop.tif"
xhash[tmax]="CHELSA_tmax10_\${MM}_1979-2013_V1.2_land_crop.tif"
xhash[prec]="CHELSA_prec_\${MM}_V1.2_land_crop.tif"

for var in ${var_list[@]} ; do

    mkdir $var
    cd $var

    for MM in 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 ; do
        eval "tif=${xhash[$var]}"
        gdal_translate -projwin $ulx $uly $lrx $lry -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co ZLEVEL=9  /vsicurl/https://os.zhdk.cloud.switch.ch/envicloud/chelsa/chelsa_V1/climatologies/${var}/$tif $tif
    done

    cd ..

done
```

Comment: no need for mkdir inside for loop. Just suggestion. and also use range `{start..end}` ie `{0..100}` would expand to 0, 1, 2, 3 ... 100.

Comment: @CEPB, yes {start..end} would be better.

Comment: I am not familiar with `gdal_translate` but I also feel like your solution could be cut down to a single loop in this case.